# FullCalendar create drop down filter

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullCalendar in my Symfony project.i wont to create client side drop down filter that filter by database value /status value/

here is my entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BookingRepository")
 */
class Booking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255 ,nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $loadingDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $unloadingDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $truck_id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $loadingAddress;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $unloadingAddress;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=0)
     */
    private $pricePerKm;
    /**
     * @var Driver
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Driver",inversedBy="cargoes")
     */
    private Driver $drivers;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer" )
     */
    private int $status = 0;
    /**
     * @var User
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="bookings")
     */
    private User $author;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLoadingDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->loadingDate;
    }

    public function setLoadingDate(\DateTimeInterface $loadingDate): self
    {
        $this->loadingDate = $loadingDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUnloadingDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->unloadingDate;
    }

    public function setUnloadingDate(?\DateTimeInterface $unloadingDate = null): self
    {
        $this->unloadingDate = $unloadingDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPricePerKm()
    {
        return $this->pricePerKm;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $pricePerKm
     */
    public function setPricePerKm($pricePerKm): void
    {
        $this->pricePerKm = $pricePerKm;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUnloadingAddress()
    {
        return $this->unloadingAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $unloadingAddress
     */
    public function setUnloadingAddress($unloadingAddress): void
    {
        $this->unloadingAddress = $unloadingAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTruckId()
    {
        return $this->truck_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $truck_id
     */
    public function setTruckId($truck_id): void
    {
        $this->truck_id = $truck_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLoadingAddress()
    {
        return $this->loadingAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $loadingAddress
     */
    public function setLoadingAddress($loadingAddress): void
    {
        $this->loadingAddress = $loadingAddress;
    }



    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->loadingAddress." to ".$this->unloadingAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title): void
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
    /**
     * @param mixed $status
     */
    public function setStatus($status): void
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }
    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getAuthor(): User
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $author
     *
     */
    public function setAuthor(User $author )
    {
        $this->author = $author;
    }
    /**
     * @return Driver
     */
    public function getDrivers(): Driver
    {
        return $this->drivers;
    }

    /**
     * @param Driver $drivers
     */
    public function setDrivers(Driver $drivers): void
    {
        $this->drivers = $drivers;
    }


}
```

my calendar subscriber

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Repository\BookingRepository;
use CalendarBundle\CalendarEvents;
use CalendarBundle\Entity\Event;
use CalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class CalendarSubscriber extends AbstractController implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private BookingRepository $bookingRepository;
    private UrlGeneratorInterface $router;

    public function __construct(
        BookingRepository $bookingRepository,
        UrlGeneratorInterface $router
    )
    {
        $this->bookingRepository = $bookingRepository;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            CalendarEvents::SET_DATA => 'onCalendarSetData',
        ];
    }
    public function onCalendarSetData(CalendarEvent $calendar)
    {
        // Modify the query to fit to your entity and needs
        // Change booking.beginAt by your start date property

        $bookings = $this->bookingRepository->findBy(['author' => $this->getUser()]);

        foreach ($bookings as $booking) {

            // this  create the events with your data (here booking data) to fill calendar
            $bookingEvent = new Event(
                $booking->getTitle(),
                $booking->getloadingDate(),
                $booking->getUnloadingDate(),

            // If the end date is null or not defined, a all day event is created.
            );

            /*
             * Add custom options to events
             *
             * For more information see: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object
             * and: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/core/options.ts
             */
            if ($booking->getStatus() != 0) {
                $bookingEvent->setOptions([
                    'backgroundColor' => 'grey',
                    'borderColor' => 'grey',
                ]);
            } else {
                $bookingEvent->setOptions([
                    'backgroundColor' => 'matblue',
                    'borderColor' => 'matblue',

                ]);
            }
            $bookingEvent->addOption(
                'url',
                $this->router->generate('booking_show', [
                    'id' => $booking->getId(),
                ])
            );

            // finally, add the event to the CalendarEvent to fill the calendar
            $calendar->addEvent($bookingEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

and view

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <a href="{{ path('booking_new') }}">Create new booking</a>

    <select id="status-filter">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="1">Completed</option>
        <option value="2">Not Completed</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <div id="calendar-holder"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.1.0/main.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.1.0/main.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.1.0/main.min.css">

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.1.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.1.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.1.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.1.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/list@4.1.0/main.min.js"></script>

    <div id="mycalendar"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar-holder');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                defaultView: 'list',
                editable: true,

                eventSources: [
                    
                    {
                        url: "{{ path('fc_load_events') }}",
                        method: "POST",
                        extraParams: {
                            filters: JSON.stringify({})
                        },
                        failure: () => {
                            // alert("There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!");
                        },
                    },
                ],
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,list',
                },

                plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid','list' ], // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/plugin-index
                timeZone: 'UTC',
                locale:"bg",

            });
            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The default status value is '0' .when the event is completed the value of the status changes то '1'

The filter must switch between values

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question, or a problem statement. We'll _help_ you with your attempt to solve your problem / implement your requirement. Please explain the code you've posted - what exact issue(s) are you facing? Where are you stuck? Don't leave us to work it out, make it easy for us to help you by explaining what you've done and where you're having difficulties. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. I also suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) Between that and the How to Ask guide, you should have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: Thank's for the advice :)
i am confused how to deal with this. The subscriber is the place which load the event.I try to pass request from select box to subscriber,but  onCalendarSetData function can't take the request

Argument 2 passed to App\EventSubscriber\CalendarSubscriber::onCalendarSetData() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, string given

maybe the easiest way is with js script,but i don't know js

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about how symfony works, I only know fullCalendar (and I know core PHP but not symfony). I did spend 2 minutes reading about subscriptions in symfony though, and it's not obvious to me why you are using a subscription for this functionality rather than a simple controller with a function?

Comment: i took this code from github and customized for my needs.This filter is the last thing that i want to add,but i stuck on it.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question

Comment: almost ready.I need help with select tag filter.Some js script i thing.When the form is submitted, everytime send first option value 
no matter what I choose